# Oracle Sequence values to file

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql, oracle11g

I wanted to write some PL-SQL script, which will increase the existing sequece of example 10000 times (let say that the current value is "12", so at the end, the current value of sequence will be "10012"), and the script will create an output file, with each executing of *.NEXTVAL*, so:

```
13
14
15
...
10012
```

Comment: Does it have to be a sequence? Why not just generate the numbers 12 to 10012?

Comment: It has to **USE** already existing sequence and it should increase this sequence of course.

Comment: I've already prepared some _increasing_ PL-SQL script, which as a parameter, gets the increasing limit:

SET VERIFY OFF;
DECLARE
 CURRENT_VALUE NUMBER := 0;
 DUMMY_VALUE NUMBER := 0;
BEGIN
 SELECT **SEQUENCE_NAME** .NEXTVAL INTO DUMMY_VALUE FROM DUAL;
 CURRENT_VALUE := DUMMY_VALUE;
 WHILE DUMMY_VALUE < (CURRENT_VALUE + &1) LOOP
  SELECT WTDOCUMENTID_seq.NEXTVAL INTO DUMMY_VALUE FROM DUAL;
 END LOOP;
END;
/

but I wanted to have those sequence numbers in output file - not just increasing code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So, in SQL*Plus you can use smth like this

```
spool myoutputfile.txt
select SEQUENCE_NAME.NEXTVAL from 
(
SELECT ROWNUM AS rn FROM DUAL
        CONNECT BY LEVEL <=10000
) a;
spool off;
```

Comment: Works like a charm with some improvements:


SET TRIMSPOOL ON HEADING OFF FEEDBACK OFF ECHO OFF 
PAGESIZE 0

SPOOL output.txt

SELECT TRIM(SEQUENCE_NAME.NEXTVAL) FROM (SELECT ROWNUM FROM DUAL CONNECT BY LEVEL <= 1000);

SPOOL OFF;

Thanks!